# PHP: Greek string from xml converted to ascii and is not comparing

Tags: php, wordpress, string, encoding, wpallimport

I am using `wpallimport` to import some categories from xml which are in Greek. I am using some custom functions in order to do some category mapping by using a database table where I store the original category and the destination category.

For example:

```
Κατηγορία α | Κατηγορία β
```

The problem is that when I am trying to compare the category from the xml: `Κατηγορία α` with the one in the database table `Κατηγορία α` even though they look the same they are not. I did `strlen` and I saw that the xml's string length is larger than it seems. With further investigation I saw that if I echo string from xml per char I get the ascii code.

So `echo $category_from_xml[0];` returns `&` (from ascii representation of the greek `Κ` letter : `&#x39a`) while `echo $category_from_database[0];` returns `Κ` .

How I can compare these 2 strings correctly?

**Example**
Database contains these values :
(Database Collation utf8_General_ci)

```
origin_cat_desc          | target_cat_desc
---------------------------------------------------
Κινητά Τηλέφωνα > Maxcom | Κινητά & Tablet > Maxcom
```

And this is the part of the XML I am trying to parse:

```
<family el="Κινητά Τηλέφωνα" en="Mobile Phones"/>
<group el="Maxcom" en="Maxcom"/>
```

And finally this is how I tried to compare the 2 strings:

***1***

```
$path = {family}.' > '.{group};
function customCompare($fromDatabase,$path){
    return ($fromDatabase == $path); //strcmp fails too
}
```

***2***

```
$path = {family}.' > '.{group};
function customCompare($fromDatabase,$path){
    $stringToHex = json_encode($fromDatabase);
    $strTest = str_replace('\u0', '&#x', $stringToHex);
    $strTest = str_replace(' ', '', $strTest);
    $path='"'.$path.'"';
    $path = str_replace(' ','',$path);
    $removeSemicolon = str_replace(';','',htmlspecialchars($path, ENT_QUOTES));
    $k = htmlspecialchars($strTest, ENT_QUOTES);
    if($k==$removeSemicolon){
         echo "same";
    }
}
```

This is the value of "Κινητά Τηλέφωνα > Maxcom" from the database when I echo it char per char:

```
"&#x39a&#x3b9&#x3bd&#x3b7&#x3c4&#x3ac &#x3a4&#x3b7&#x3bb&#x3ad&#x3c6&#x3c9&#x3bd&#x3b1 > Maxcom"
```

Comment: How do you compare compare strings? `strcmp` is binary safe

Comment: I tried with both `strcmp` and `=` but both fail...

Comment: Can you show full example? With hardcoded values and comparison? Maybe you somewhere mess up encoding? Maybe you do not use proper `mb_` function?

Comment: @Justinas I updated my post with an example